# Left eigenvector of stochastic matrices with eigenvalue 1

Tags: linear-algebra, markov-chains

I am only talking about matrices for finite number of states.

By the existence of unique equilibrium distribution, this surely means there can only be one of such eigenvector (i.e. the eigenvalue 1 has geometric multiplicity of 1)

Is it possible such a matrix to have eigenvalue 1 repeated?

Comment: Any extra information about reducibility?

Comment: @thanasissdr i have an irreducible markov chain in mind, hence the comment about the uniqueness of equilibrium distribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any $n\times n$ stochastic matrix $P$, it is true that
$$\left|\lambda_i\right| \le 1,\quad i = 1, \ldots, n.$$ Also, we can easily prove that $\lambda = 1$ is an eigenvalue of matrix $P$.
Combining these facts, it holds that the spectral radius of $P$ is $\rho(P) = 1$.

Due to irreducibility, we may apply the [Perron - Frobenius theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perron-Frobenius_theorem#Perron.E2.80.93Frobenius_theorem_for_irreducible_matrices) to the stochastic matrix $P$ and we get that $\lambda = 1$ is a simple eigenvalue.

Thus, $\lambda = 1$ **cannot** be repeated.

Comment: I assume that eigenvalue smaller than 1 follows by the fact it is stochastic. Assume it is not, then you can contradict the fact it is not stochastic?.

Comment: I guess you are interested in the proof of my first statement. I think you can find a short proof [here](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~knill/teaching/math19b_2011/handouts/lecture33.pdf).

Comment: nice, are you at havard?

Comment: @Lost1 No! But if you keep searching online, you may find a lot of stuff hosted under great academic institute sites. :p